# Trouble with JavaScript onSubmit from HTML Form

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

This is probably a very simple oversight on my behalf, but I cannot get the below to run.

I am triggering this function at the press of a button in a form element. If I run this outside of the getData() function it works correctly (with a manually coded URL), but trying to run the function does not work.

Could someone please take a look at this and advise where I may be going wrong?

```
function getData(form) {
    var url = '/service/search/' + form.date.value;
    var getStats = new XMLHttpRequest();
    getStats.open('GET', url, true);
    getStats.onload = function() {
        if (getStats.status = 200) {
            //Add JSON to "data"
            var data = JSON.parse(getStats.responseText);
            var list = '';
            if (data.length > 0) {
                document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '<tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Title</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>'
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                list += '<tr data-state="'+data[i].state+'" class="'+data[i].type+'-item"><td class="crm-'+data[i].state+'"></td><td>'+data[i].start+'</td><td>'+data[i].end+'</td><td>'+data[i].title+'</td><td><a href="xxxxxxxx'+data[i].id+'" target="_blank">View</a></td>';
            }
            //document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += list;
            console.log(list);
        } else {
            console.error('HTTP ERROR: ' + getStats.status);
        }
    };
    getStats.onerror = function() {
        console.error('ERROR');
    };
    getStats.send();
}
```

**UPDATE**
As requested, this is how I am calling the function:

```
<form onsubmit="getData(this);">
     <input type="text" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" id="date">
     <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

In regards to when this works correctly, if I run the below outside of a function it works:

```
var url = '/service/search/2014-06-11';
var getStats = new XMLHttpRequest();
getStats.open('GET', url, true);
getStats.onload = function() {
    if (getStats.status = 200) {
        //Add JSON to "data"
        var data = JSON.parse(getStats.responseText);
        var list = '';
        if (data.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '<tr><th>&nbsp;</th><th>Start</th><th>End</th><th>Title</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr>'
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            list += '<tr data-state="'+data[i].state+'" class="'+data[i].type+'-item"><td class="crm-'+data[i].state+'"></td><td>'+data[i].start+'</td><td>'+data[i].end+'</td><td>'+data[i].title+'</td><td><a href="xxxxxxxx'+data[i].id+'" target="_blank">View</a></td>';
        }
        //document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += list;
        console.log(list);
    } else {
        console.error('HTTP ERROR: ' + getStats.status);
    }
};
getStats.onerror = function() {
    console.error('ERROR');
};
getStats.send();
```

Comment: Can you post how you are calling this function in the case where it works and the case where it does not work?

Comment: @MarkCarpenter - I've updated the original post with this data. Thanks.

Comment: can you add an alert(form.date.value); at the beginning of the function to ensure you are getting the date value you are expecting?

Comment: @MarkCarpenter I added in the alert(form.date.value) as tried the form with "2014-01-01". It correctly alerted with "2014-01-01".